# How to access classes from a module imported template literals?

Tags: javascript, module

Importing module with a template literals inside can access only global variables. How can access variable from a class?

template.js ( targeting class )

```
export var literal = {
        base: `<h1>${ foo.copy.ternary }</h1>
                <div>${ foo.copy.title }</div>
                `
   }
```

index.html ( In the example below i get a ***ReferenceError: Can't find variable*** )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id=host></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        class Foo {
            constructor() {
                this.copy = {
                    title: 'Discovering Template Literals',
                    subtitle: 'Effortless client-side rendering awaits.',
                    body: 'You will never want to go back to normal strings again.',
                    ternary: 'Ternary Condition'
                };
            };
        };


    </script>

    <script type="module">

        let foo = new Foo();

        import * as templates from './templates.js'
        document.getElementById( "host" ).innerHTML = templates.literal.base;

    </script>

</html>
```

template.js

```
export var literal = {
        base: `<h1>${ copy.ternary }</h1>
                <div>${ copy.title }</div>
                `
   }
```

index.html ( **working with global variable** )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id=host></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var copy = {
                    title: 'Discovering Template Literals',
                    subtitle: 'Effortless client-side rendering awaits.',
                    body: 'You will never want to go back to normal strings again.',
                    ternary: 'Ternary Condition'
        };

    </script>

    <script type="module">

        import * as templates from './templates.js'
        document.getElementById( "host" ).innerHTML = templates.literal.base;

    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
export var literal = {
        base: `<h1>${ foo.copy.ternary }</h1>
                <div>${ foo.copy.title }</div>
                `
}
```

will interpolate the result of evaluating `foo.copy.ternary`, etc into the constructed string that gets assigned to the `base` property. But `foo` is not in scope of the module, so an error will be thrown, *when the module is run*.

Rather than exporting a template literal (which would be the same as exporting a static string, errors aside), export a *function* which takes `foo` as a parameter, evaluates the template literal *in the function*, and returns the constructed string:

```
export var literal = {
  base(foo) {
    return `<h1>${ foo.copy.ternary }</h1>
            <div>${ foo.copy.title }</div>
            `;
  }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
document.getElementById( "host" ).innerHTML = templates.literal.base(foo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.